# Checking if all elements in a vector equals one string with a for loop

Tags: c++

I want to check if all words in a string vector equals one single string. Say I have the vector `vector<string> words = { "birds", "flies", "but", "fish", "swim" };` and I want to check if all these elements combined equals a string with a for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
    cout << words[i];
    if (words[i] == "birdsfliesbutfishswim") {
        sentenceCorrect = true;
    }
}
```

Right now, the code will print out `words[i]` as "*birdsfliesbutfishswim*" but it will not equal the string inside the for loop. Though, the string inside the for loop is also "*birdsfliesbutfishswim*". Why is that? Why can I not compare `words[i]` to a string as the example above? And what would make it work?

Comment: Why not just use [std::all_of, std::any_of, std::none_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) ?

Comment: _"Though, the string inside the for loop is also "birdsfliesbutfishswim"."_ What? Which string? _`words[i]`_ still contains one of the individual strings.

Comment: Alright, I'll see if that works. Also, why is every (And I mean every) single question I ask on this page always disliked? I have never experienced this rudeness from any other webpage in my life.

Comment: "... I want to check if all these elements combined..." you dont combine the strings. you compare each single element to the full string, but there is no "birdsfliesbutfishswim" in the vector

Comment: @spec not my downvote, but if was to guess, I'd say: because your questions don't include a [mcve], nor indicate much effort into research on your own.

Comment: One loop to concatenate each string in the vector into one large string, and then one comparison to the generated string? The first part, the loop, could be replaced by e.g. [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: Or, you know, create a second vector containing the exact strings you want compare with, and then just compare the two vectors?

Comment: @spec _"Also, why is every (And I mean every) single question I ask on this page always disliked?"_ Before investing time into start to complain  about that, you might better use it to improve your [debugging skills](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging).

Comment: _why is every_ if they are all like this one ...

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for the link, I will make sure to check it out. I am actually a pretty experienced forum user in mathematics, and I haven't gotten critized by how I ask questions on other pages. But nonetheless, I just wanna learn. I've been stuck with trying to make grammar for my C++ code for a very long time now.

Comment: @TheDude it's a genuine question and not even a complaint. I am not trying to offend any of you. I just want to know why I got so much rep on other forums. But once I got over to StackOverflow I get dislikes on everything I write?

Comment: @spec Did you read the link?

Comment: @TheDude yeah, it's very useful. Thank you!

Comment: @spec You also may have noticed the URL. Thus you know why now.

Comment: @TheDude yeah precisely, I appreciate it

Comment: btw downvotes are not necessarily about likes or dislikes. There are many quite objective measures for the quality of a question. For example you would need to change only little to turn your snippet into a [mcve], which is something that every question should contain

Comment: @user463035818 what do you feel would be the cause of the dislike in this situation?

Comment: @spec please read my comment again carefully. I said downvotes are **not** necessarily about likes or dislikes. There is nothing subjective in the fact that you didnt include a mcve, when it would take you minor effort to provide one. (btw I am not complaining here, in this particular case the example is rather clear even without being complete, just trying to explain...)

Comment: @user463035818 I think I see it now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if all of the strings combined equals your string, use the following:

```
string totalWord;
for (const auto& word : words)
{
    totalWord += word;
}
```

This combines all of the strings into one string. You could even do this one line using [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
string totalWord = std::accumulate(words.begin(), words.end(), std::string{});
```

After this, just check if the new string equals what you want to check:

```
if (totalWord == "birdsfliesbutfishswim")
{
    sentenceCorrect = true;
}
```

Comment: `std::reduce` seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare "birdsfliesbutfishswim" to all the strings in the vector combined you actually need to combine them. You dont need to write the loop yourself, but you can use an algorithm to do that:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric> 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words = { "birds", "flies", "but", "fish", "swim" };
    std::string sentence = std::accumulate(words.begin(),words.end(),std::string());
    if (sentence == "birdsfliesbutfishswim") std::cout << "dogscanswimtoo\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good old way without constructing new strings.

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include <iostream>

bool isSentenceCorrect(const char* sentence, const std::vector<std::string>& words) {
    for(const auto& word : words){
        auto word_size = word.size();
        if(word.compare(0, word_size, sentence, word_size) != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        sentence += word_size;
    }
    return *sentence == '\0';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words = {"birds", "flies", "but", "fish", "swim"};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << isSentenceCorrect("birdsfliesbutfishswim", words);
    return 0;
}
```